# Typescript: Cloning existing interface and converting its properties to 'string' type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following interfaces, lets say:

```
interface A {
  innerA: InnerA;
  innerB: InnerB;
}

interface InnerA {
  items: Item[];
  name: string;
  counter: number;
}

interface InnerB {
  address: string;
  code: number;
}

interface Item {
  id: number;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a type or an interface which will have the same keys (including keys of nested objects) as interface 'A', but each of these keys should have a value of type 'string' or, in case it is an object, recursively take its keys and make values of type 'string'. If a key has corresponding value of array type (like InnerA.items), the value of 'items' key should be of type 'Item'.

The following object should describe what I want to get, but I can't figure out a proper type for this:

```
const labels: CloneType<A> = {
  innerA: { 
    items: { id: 'ID' },
    name: 'Some Name',
    counter: 'Some Counter'
  },
  innerB: {
    address: 'Address',
    code: 'Postal Code'
  }
}

const postalCodeLabel: string = labels.innerB.code;
const itemIdLabel: string = labels.innerA.items.id;
```

I've tried the following, but stuck on converting array types and also struggling to make it recursive:

```
type CloneType<Model> = {
  // take keys of generic type
  [modelKey in keyof Model]: {
    // take fields of nested types
    [field in keyof Model[modelKey]]: string;
  }
}
```

To be honest I doubt it is possible to achieve what I'm trying to do using just pure types, but who knows, maybe it is possible and someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it's an array, and if it is, we clone the element type, otherwise, we clone it if it's an object, and if it's not any of them, give back a string. Note that this will break for things like `Map` and `Set` because those count as objects, so you'll end up with things like `{ has: string; add: string; ... }` for them.

```
type CloneType<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]:
        T[K] extends (infer E)[]
            ? CloneType<E>[]
            : T[K] extends object
                ? CloneType<T[K]>
                : string;
}
```

Assuming that your input is simple, it should work.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WzeYkm)

Comment: This turns arrays into objects. I recommend this adjustment:
`CloneType<E[]>` instead of `CloneType<E>`

Comment: @MattDeKok Solid catch on a 1 year old answer :)

Comment: @katniss This is awesome! Doesn't seem to work if the property is optional, though. For example, in your playground demo, try making `InnerA.items` optional using a question mark. Any idea how to handle that scenario?

Comment: @Travesty3 What error does that raise? I excluded undefined and it works: https://tsplay.dev/Nn56kw

Comment: @katniss Looks like it works with your update to exclude undefined. Thanks!

Comment: @katniss Any reason not to update your answer with that change? I can do it but I always feel out of place modifying someone else's answer.

Comment: @Travesty3 It doesn't really make sense to edit an answer to answer a slightly different question. You can add another answer to address your more specific problem instead.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @katniss solved my issue except for a case where the interface had an optional property. In that scenario, it would infer the type as `string` instead of recognizing that it should be an array or undefined.

I took their updated answer and took it one step further and added a second generic to make it more reusable by allowing you to specify what the new type should be:

```js
type CloneType<TModel, TNewType> = {
  [key in keyof TModel]: Exclude<TModel[key], undefined> extends Array<infer E>
    ? Array<CloneType<E, TNewType>>
    : Exclude<TModel[key], undefined> extends object
      ? CloneType<TModel[key], TNewType>
      : TNewType;
};
}
```

Note the addition of `Exclude<TModel[key], undefined>`. Now, it will work properly if, for instance, the `InnerA.items` property is optional:

```js
interface InnerA {
  items?: Item[];
  name: string;
  counter: number;
}
```

https://tsplay.dev/Nn56kw